# Como checar integridade do backup SQL

Tags: mysql, backup

Estou usando `MySQL` e, para fazer o backup dos bancos, estou utilizando o `mysqldump`.
Minha dúvida é se e como eu posso verificar se o arquivo gerado pelo dump está íntegro de forma automática, sem precisar "subir" o *dump* no banco?

Comment: Acho que isso pode te ajudar: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/60774/35944. Pelo que entendi da resposta, não é possível garantir a integridade sem dar um restore, porém é possível automatizar esse restore e checagem. 
Preciso fazer a mesma coisa no servidor do trabalho e farei com base nessa resposta. Caso dê certo, posto como resposta uma tradução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dê uma olhada nesta documentação, poderá lhe ajudar :

checksum é um  recurso para verificar a integridade e autenticidade dos pacotes.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/checksum-table.html

Comment: muito boa a sua resposta, mas você poderia me dar um exemplo de como eu poderia utilizar na prática?